# Random effect in linear mixed-effect model for repeated-measures study design using the lme function in R

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I have a group of subjects (`name`) which are tested for a variable of interest (`var_y`) along 5 different sessions (`session`). These sessions are not programmed for the same days for all the subjects, so it happens that in the same `date` some subjects are tested for different sessions or, viceversa the same session can be carried out during different days.
I am interested to understand if some characteristics of the subjects (namely, `gender` and `age`) have some significant influence on my variable of interest (`var_y`).

Here I report an example of dataframe:

```
ds_ex <- data.frame(name = rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"),1, each = 5),
                 date = c("2020-10-13","2020-10-14","2020-10-14","2020-10-16","2020-10-19","2020-10-13","2020-10-14","2020-10-14",
                          "2020-10-16","2020-10-19","2020-10-13","2020-10-14","2020-10-14","2020-10-16","2020-10-19","2020-10-13",
                          "2020-10-14","2020-10-14","2020-10-16","2020-10-19","2020-10-13","2020-10-14","2020-10-14","2020-10-16",
                          "2020-10-19","2020-10-13","2020-10-14","2020-10-14","2020-10-16","2020-10-19","2020-10-13","2020-10-14",
                          "2020-10-14","2020-10-16","2020-10-19","2020-11-03","2020-11-04","2020-11-04","2020-11-06","2020-11-09",
                          "2020-11-03","2020-11-04","2020-11-04","2020-11-06","2020-11-09","2020-11-03","2020-11-04","2020-11-04",
                          "2020-11-06","2020-11-09"),
                 session = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5),5),
                 gender = rep(c("M","F","M","F","M","F","F","F","F","F"),1, each = 5),
                 age = rep(c(3,12,4,2,6,13,20,16,10,8),1,each = 5),
                 var_y = floor(runif(50, min=14, max=123)))
```

I'm trying to figure out which is the best model structure for this data. I believe I should run a Mixed-effect model using `gender` and `age` as fixed variables, and `name`, `session` and `date` to build the random effect. In particular, I think (but I might be wrong) that the model should account for individual differences between subjects, the session grouping (as I expect my `var_y` varies along sessions) and the fact that the session and date are (partially?) crossed in each other.

I would need some help to:

- Understand the correct structure for the random effect to implement in the model
- Code correctly the chosen structure using the `lme` function from the `nlme` package (as I need to obtain an lme object for further analysis, which requires that class object).

Comment: So just to be sure a person can have multiple sessions in one day? Or are the differences in time between each session the same for each individual? So for example between Session 1 and Session two there always 5 day?

The problem with your idea is that how would you structure, date and session hierarchically. Like with you plan you would have a 4 level Model. So Name would be your highest level, and then which of the two other variables would follow? It is probably better to decide whether you expect a bigger variance across time or across the tasks.

Comment: The experimental design is quite weird and I guess it can be prone to misinterpreting the effects of some of the variables of interest. So we have 7 individuals (namely a,b,c,d,e,f,g) that had their first session on 13Oct, the 2nd and 3rd sessions on 14Oct, 4th on 16Oct, and 5th on 19Oct. The last three individuals (h,i,j) undergo their sessions on 3Nov (1st session), 4Nov (2nd and 3rd), 6Nov (4th) and 9Nov (5th). I am afraid that the timeframe with which the various sessions have been arranged might influence the result and affect the interpretation of the coefficient of the predictors.